# Unusual icon in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, ide

I've just hit an accidental key-combination in Visual Studio Professional 2015 on a `.css` file, and I now have a "top-right arrow" icon in the breakpoint panel I've never seen before.

I have no idea what the symbol means, or what key-combination I did to get it...

[image]

Double clicking and right clicking does nothing.

Closing/reopening the file/solution doesn't get rid of it.

There is no tool-tip when I hover over it.

What is it, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Not "possible", definite... thanks @Mooseman

Comment: No problem. You can vote to close as dupe as well.

Comment: For future reference (for when I do it again and find my own question)... the key-combination was `Ctrl-K-H` in VS2015